# Equivalent of completely multiplicative function for dot product

Tags: number-theory, functions

Does there exist an equivalent to the set of completely multiplicative functions ie functions for which $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$ for the dot product?

Ie I'm looking for equations satisfying $$f(X\cdot Y) = f(X)\cdot f(Y)$$ for some vectors $X,Y$ (ideally with $X,Y \in \mathbb{R}^d$) or potentially any other operation such that $$f(X\cdot Y) = f(X)\circ f(Y)$$ Apart from obvious solutions like constant functions or identity, I can't come up with any as the other solutions to completely multiplicative functions, most importantly power functions (and also obviously Cauchy functional equations) do not work.

One issue is the domain of the function $f(X)$, so either we define that to be $\mathbb{R} \cup \mathbb{R}^d$ or we need two functions $f(X): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g(x): \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f((X \cdot Y)) = g(X) \cdot g(Y)$ - or, as mentioned above, we use another operation for $f(X) \circ f(Y)$ s.t. $f(X) \circ f(Y) \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? When we talk about multiplicative functions, we use that product of natural numbers is natural number. But dot product of vectors isn't vector.

Comment: Yes that's where I got stuck as well ... I feel it'd have to be $\mathbb{R}^d$ and then be a function that takes either a vector or some scalar.

Comment: So, you are essentially interested in two functions, $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f((X, Y)) = g(X) \cdot g(Y)$?

Comment: I am not sure, isn't it fine as long as $f(X) \cdot f(Y) \in \mathbb{R}$ ? Yes I see how there's an issue with the function domain but if $f(x)$ can be applied to both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^d$ eg $f(x)=cx$ would work in both cases - is there no way around this?

Comment: Formally $f$ can be defined on $\mathbb R \cup \mathbb R^d$, but such functions have natural one-to-one correspondence with pairs of functions on $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: Ok so ... do you think the only way is to have 2 separate functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ ? I guess they could even do the same thing just on different domains. And assuming that - how do we then proceed for a solution?

Comment: They can't do "same thing", because even multiplication by constant is different operation for vectors and numbers. We formally can merge this two functions into single on union of their domains, but I think it just complicates notation. About solution - note that left part doesn't depend on specific $x$ and $y$ as long as $x \perp y$. This gives strong conditions on right part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is to find functions $f, g, h$ s.t. $f((X, Y)) = h(g(X), g(Y))$. The first variant is $h(a, b) = a \cdot b$.

Assume $d > 1$ and $g \not \equiv 0$. Choose $x$ s.t. $g(x) \neq 0$, $y \perp x$ and let $X = \lambda x$, $Y = \mu y$. We get $f(0) = f((X, Y)) = g(\lambda x) \cdot g(\mu y)$. As left part doesn't depend on $\mu$ and $\lambda$, right part doesn't depend on them either - implying $g(\lambda x)$ and $g(\mu y)$ are constants. Taking $\lambda = \mu = 0$ we get $g(\lambda x) = g(0)$ and $g(\lambda y) = g(0)$.

If there exists $x \neq 0$ s.t. $g(x) \neq 0$, taking $X = \lambda x$, $Y = \mu x$ we get $f(\lambda \mu \|x\|^2) = g(\lambda x) g(\mu x) = g(0)^2$. As $\lambda \mu \|x\|^2$ is arbitrary number, $f \equiv g(0)^2$. And then $g$ is constant too.

So, if $g(x) \neq 0$ for some $x \neq 0$, then $g$ is constant. If $\forall x \neq 0: g(x) = 0$ then $f(0) = f((X, 0)) = g(X) \cdot g(0)$. If $X \neq 0$ then right part is equal to $0$, thus $f(0) = 0$ and so $g(0) = 0$ too.

So, if $h(a, b) = a \cdot b$, then $g$ is constant.

If $h$ is arbitrary, it's simple - choose any $f$, let $g$ be your favorite injection $\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ and say $h(a, b) = f((g^{-1}(a), g^{-1}(b)))$.